# Custom Actionbar remove left and right space issue

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have custom actionbar but it gives some margin from left and right. I don't want any margin from left or right. I have tried some solutions but there is no progress. How can i remove them ? Thanks in advance

custom_actionbar.xml:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/yazi"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TableRow>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgSideBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:background="@mipmap/menu_open" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtBaslik"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Some text"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtAsamaSayisi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="1/24"
        android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_9sdp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgArrows"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@mipmap/left_right_arrows"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

And my java class:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

    //Setting custom actionbar
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar);

    //Some codes...
}
```

And screenshot of my result. As you can see there are some margins from left and right.

[image: Screenshot]

**Edit:** my main xml codes:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center"
tools:context="com.cybersoft.intvrg.BeyannameDoldur">


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
</FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My styles.xml code:

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--<item name="contentInsetStart">0dp</item>-->
    <!--<item name="contentInsetEnd">0dp</item>-->
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@null</item>
</style>
```

Comment: please post your full xml code

Comment: @Raja I added already all of my code about the actionbar.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya i set an actionbar programmatically.

Comment: seems like there is margin on actvity_main_menu xml layout

Comment: In main.xml, i used only one framelayout inside relativelayout.

Comment: can u show actvity_main_menu xml  layout

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are defining a margin somewhere in your java code, I can't see any other way it should display like that. Maybe you can find it yourself or you can show us the Java Code where you are defining the actionbar.

Additionally, the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html) says that TableRow enforces its children to always use `MATCH_PARENT` and `WRAP_CONTENT` for `layout_width` and `layout_height` respectively. This could lead to some issue, if not specified correctly.

Best regards.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17681519)

Comment: @AlexanderMorland I get what you are saying and I understand why this barrier is in place. But I think that I still gave an answer to his question in the last paragraph, saying that he has to have a margin defined somewhere in his code. But as I was not able to ask for that additional information in a comment, I had to give a more vague answer. And I just couldn't leave out the documentation part, maybe I should have put that last, sorry for that...

Comment: I suggest you edit the answer, to remove the needless fill and commentary and leave only a clear answer. If you are not able to answer the question, because maybe it is to vaguely put, then the question needs to be fixed (or removed).

Answer (score 1):

- Call [**`View`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) class .
- You should add [**`LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#MATCH_PARENT)

> Special value for the height or width requested by a View.
>   MATCH_PARENT means that the view wants to be as big as its parent,
>   minus the parent's padding, if any

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

View viewOBJ = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar,null);
LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(viewOBJ, layoutParams);
```

Comment: There are some margins from top and bottom, they are gone but left and right spaces still exist.

Comment: Sorry but same problem.

Comment: @CagriYalcin in `TableLayout ` section create `RelativeLayout` as parent

Comment: @CagriYalcin Make sure you are using `v7.app.ActionBar` ?

Comment: Thanks for comment, i'm trying now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157122/discussion-between-cagri-yalcin-and-intellij-amiya).

Answer (score 0):

This happens because ActionBar keep some space for "Home" button and some others.

To remove them, you have to add this properties in your root action bar Layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarFromActivityB"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp">
    <TableLayout 
        ...
        >
    />
```

As you can see you have tu put your layout from your action bar inside a android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar. Later you will have to inflate it with setSupportActionBar(toolbar) being toolbar the view from XML before (toolbarFromActivityB).

As you have your toolbar in other file, you will have to include it in your activity xml (`<include layout="@layout/custom_actionbar" />`)

Don't get the existing "actionbar" and inflate a customview. Instead of that set a new toolbar for your new Activity.

Comment: I see you are making a Toolbar for your Activity, some advices:

1) Don't use TableLayout, use Relative or Linear instead.

2) Try the last part i told you in the response (setsupportactionbar) using a RelativeLayout)

Comment: I checked your updated answer. One question. I set an id to TableLayout but how can i handle it as Toolbar ?

Comment: Handle like what

Comment: Check the response, I show you how to get a Toolbar from that XML.

Comment: toolbarActivityB is and id of TableLayout, but in your last code you are calling as a Toolbar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157121/discussion-between-manuel-sanchez-and-cagri-yalcin).

Comment: toolbarActivityB is the id from toolbar. You have to put your xml layout inside a Toolbar in XML. Just put all inside <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar ...> </<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>